# How to get the array inside array of json response in angular 10?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```json
  "CongnitiveSearchResult":{
      "value":[
         {
            "DisplayTags":[
               "Cross-Function",
               "Retail",
               "Oil & Gas",
               "Manufacturing"
            ]
         }
```

I want to get `displaytags` length in each response for ex. `response[o]` has `displaytags` length `3` and I have to get it similarly for each response. I have to get and loop it in html for each div. The problem here is length is not exactly given for each response it is taking differently for ex, `0th` response length is `1` but actual length is `3` and so I don't know what is happening. Please note `displaytags` may also be `empty` or `null` sometimes.

Comment: Use `.map(value => value.DisplayTags)` function for your json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to iterate them in template then take `DisplayTags` array instead of just their length.

To get all `DisplayTags` array

```
  displayTags: string[][];

  constructor() {
    this.displayTags = CongnitiveSearchResult.value.map((o) =>
      o.DisplayTags ? o.DisplayTags : []
    );
  }
```

In template to iterate:

```
<div *ngFor="let arr of displayTags">
  <div *ngFor="let item of arr">
    {{ item }}
  </div>
  <hr />
</div>
```

Or to display according to value

```
<div *ngFor="let val of CongnitiveSearchResult.value">
  <b>Name</b> : {{ val.Name }}<br />
  <b>Display Tags:</b>
  <ol>
    <li *ngFor="let item of val.DisplayTags ? val.DisplayTags : []">
      {{ item }}
    </li>
  </ol>
  <hr />
</div>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sikimz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: All the tags are displayed in each div but i want tags corresponding to each div.,for ex, apple,android,tv are the tags of 1st response and duno,jio,gre are the tags for 2nd response now the tags apple,android,tv,duno,jio,gre are displayed in each tile but it should display as per the response right?

Comment: response you mean `value` property?

Comment: Yes it should be displayed per value i have each div seperate for each value i am displaying other properties like tagname description etc in each tile in addition to tag i should display the tags of each value.

Comment: check the updated answer, also demo updated

Comment: Ok... Thank you so much for detailed answer about html binding also

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
let response_displaytags_lengths = CongnitiveSearchResult.value.map(item => item.DisplayTags? item.DisplayTags.length: 0);
```

Here is working example:

```js
const CongnitiveSearchResult = {
  "value":[
     {
        "@search.score":6.755926,
        "Id":"932b3a70-630e-4fb8-3a8d-08d91c6c03ac",
        "Name":"ZBS Closed Loop",
        "ShortDescription":"All six phases of the ZBS closed loop framework which help drive sustainable outcomes for clients",
        "Description":"All six phases of the ZBS closed loop framework which help drive sustainable outcomes for clients",
        "Date":"2021-05-21T15:20:49.317Z",
        "Type":"Project Model",
        "DisplayOrder":31,
        "ArchetypeVersionUId":"e959266c-0711-443b-6b1b-08d91c6c03d4",
        "RelatedArchTypeName":"",
        "RelatedToolName":"Enterprise Value Targeting",
        "PHASENAME":"Value Targeting",
        "SUBPHASENAME":"2.2 Quantify",
        "Tags":"Cross-Function, ZBS Closed Loop, ZBX, ZBS, Zero Based, Zero Based Spend, Visibility, Value Targeting, Category Ownership, Budgeting, Zero Based Budgeting, Execute Initiatives, Control, Monitoring",
        "IsRecommended":true,
        "isFavourite":false,
        "Duration":"",
        "PhaseCount":6,
        "Score":40.0,
        "WebsiteUrl":null,
        "ActivityName":"",
        "productContacts":null,
        "productIndustries":null,
        "productIndustrieFunctions":null,
        "ArchetypeIndustries":[
           {
              "ProductVersionIndustryUId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
              "ProductVersionIndustryId":0,
              "ProductVersionUId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
              "IndustryUId":"b088760a-ba6e-4058-c8e1-08d91c6c03f1",
              "Code":null,
              "Name":"Cross Industry",
              "Description":"Cross Industry",
              "DisplayOrder":1
           },
           {
              "ProductVersionIndustryUId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
              "ProductVersionIndustryId":0,
              "ProductVersionUId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
              "IndustryUId":"c8014dc7-60bc-eb11-9173-3822e2242831",
              "Code":null,
              "Name":"ZBX",
              "Description":"ZBX",
              "DisplayOrder":100040001000100000
           },
           {
              "ProductVersionIndustryUId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
              "ProductVersionIndustryId":0,
              "ProductVersionUId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
              "IndustryUId":"c9014dc7-60bc-eb11-9173-3822e2242831",
              "Code":null,
              "Name":"ZBS",
              "Description":"ZBS",
              "DisplayOrder":100040001000200000
           }
        ],
        "ArchetypeIndustryFunctions":[
           {
              "ProductVersionIndustryFunctionUId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
              "ProductVersionIndustryFunctionId":0,
              "ProductVersionUId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
              "IndustryFunctionUId":"2f7f9af1-b81f-4a05-c8e2-08d91c6c03f1",
              "Code":null,
              "Name":"Cross-Function",
              "Description":"Cross-Function",
              "RowStatusUId":null,
              "DisplayOrder":1
           }
        ],
        "ActivityModelGroups":null,
        "DisplayTags":[
           "Cross-Function",
           "Cross Industry",
           "ZBX",
           "ZBS"
        ]
     },
     {
        "@search.score":5.6102304,
        "Id":"00000030-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "Name":"ZBSC Spend Assessment",
        "ShortDescription":"The objective of Visibility and Value Targeting is to map the current organization, compare it to internal and external benchmarks before arriving at agreed targets for the key categories across the Supply Chain",
        "Description":"The objective of Visibility and Value Targeting is to map the current organization, compare it to internal and external benchmarks before arriving at agreed targets for the key categories across the Supply Chain",
        "Date":"2021-05-18T14:13:05.91Z",
        "Type":"Project Model",
        "DisplayOrder":30,
        "ArchetypeVersionUId":"00000030-0010-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "RelatedArchTypeName":"",
        "RelatedToolName":"Enterprise Value Targeting",
        "PHASENAME":"Value Targeting",
        "SUBPHASENAME":"2.2 QUANTIFY",
        "Tags":"Cross-Function, ZBSC Spend Assessment, ZBx, ZBS, Retail, Oil & Gas, Manufacturing, Cost transformation, Strategic Cost Transformation , AI",
        "IsRecommended":true,
        "isFavourite":false,
        "Duration":"3-6 months",
        "PhaseCount":2,
        "Score":40.0,
        "WebsiteUrl":null,
        "ActivityName":"",
        "productContacts":null,
        "productIndustries":null,
        "productIndustrieFunctions":null,
        "ArchetypeIndustries":[
           {
              "ProductVersionIndustryUId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
              "ProductVersionIndustryId":0,
              "ProductVersionUId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
              "IndustryUId":"7ad63249-64ad-eb11-ba5f-002b671584c6",
              "Code":null,
              "Name":"Retail",
              "Description":"Retail",
              "DisplayOrder":100020001000100000
           },
           {
              "ProductVersionIndustryUId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
              "ProductVersionIndustryId":0,
              "ProductVersionUId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
              "IndustryUId":"7bd63249-64ad-eb11-ba5f-002b671584c6",
              "Code":null,
              "Name":"Oil & Gas",
              "Description":"Oil & Gas",
              "DisplayOrder":100020001000200000
           },
           {
              "ProductVersionIndustryUId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
              "ProductVersionIndustryId":0,
              "ProductVersionUId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
              "IndustryUId":"7cd63249-64ad-eb11-ba5f-002b671584c6",
              "Code":null,
              "Name":"Manufacturing",
              "Description":"Manufacturing",
              "DisplayOrder":100020001000300000
           }
        ],
        "ArchetypeIndustryFunctions":[
           {
              "ProductVersionIndustryFunctionUId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
              "ProductVersionIndustryFunctionId":0,
              "ProductVersionUId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
              "IndustryFunctionUId":"9d001512-65ad-eb11-ba5f-002b671584c6",
              "Code":null,
              "Name":"Cross-Function",
              "Description":"Cross-Function",
              "RowStatusUId":null,
              "DisplayOrder":100020002000100000
           }
        ],
        "ActivityModelGroups":null,
        "DisplayTags":[
           "Cross-Function",
           "Retail",
           "Oil & Gas",
           "Manufacturing"
        ]
     }
  ]
}
     
let response_displaytags_lengths = CongnitiveSearchResult.value.map(item => item.DisplayTags? item.DisplayTags.length: 0);
console.log(response_displaytags_lengths)
```

Comment: Thank you i will check and let you know

Comment: Thank you it was very helpful to understand my problem

Comment: Welcome. Consider also accepting and upvoting my answer if it helped you.

Comment: I upvoted your answer already.Just one question how do i display the display tags for each div for some div displaytags is coming as empty i don't know why but i do have tags in that.